# Archive Sites and Lists in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, site-collection, site, content-and-structure

I want to move/copy the lists and sites to other site collection using

> Content and Structure feature

in Site Settings. Is it possible to move/copy to other site collection ?
If yes, then when I restore the list, then will the lookup will remain as it is or it will remove ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can back up and restore and surely get your lookup as it is. You can use Powershell to export and import.

Comment: Export-spweb –identity http://xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxx -path c:\xxxx.bak

Comment: Import-spweb –identity http://xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxx  -path c:\xxxxx.bak

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
Backup-SPSite http://siteurl -Path C:\Backup\xxxx.bak

Restore-SPSite siteurl -Path C:\Backup\xxx.bak
```